# node.js DIGEST-MD5 calculation: calculate 16 octect MD5 hash

Tags: node.js, sasl

I'm trying to implement DIGEST-MD5 with node.js but it doesn't seem to work correctly. 
Currently, I tried to implement it the following way:

```
function md5(str) {
    var hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
    hash.update(str);
    return hash.digest('binary');
}

var A1 = md5(username + ':' + realm + ':' + password);
```

When I console.log this value (with username = "test", realm = "" and password = "123), the following appears: "EïSÓ*JÉHF7{"

I compared this with the javascript implementation of strophe.js (which is correct) and this prints the following "EïSÓ*JÉHF7{¢"

Is there another way on how to calculate it? Or is it maybe some wrong encoding of the base string?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: I get `EïS\u0004Ó*JÉH\u000eF7{\u000f¢` with your code, but the `¢` character seems to disappear sometimes (when copying from the terminal, for example). Looks like the hash is correct but you're having encoding issues.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the correct answer. I tried a little bit with encoding but lastly I was using the wrong variables.. grmbl :(

Answer (score 0):

I;m using node v0.4.12 and i am getting:
EïSÓ*JÉHF7{¢

which version of node you are using?

maybe this is shell settings thing try execute unix command:

env

search for:
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Yeah it seems to be an encoding issue somehow. But using also UTF-8 as the encoding in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [module](https://github.com/gevorg/http-auth), I've tested this and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now, my code was correct but I used some wrong variables for constructing the string..

Thanks for the help.